# User interfirance, themes, Broken, Unreadable parts

Tags: unity, themes

Arther going on a customizing spree my the desktop themes on unity got messed up I had installed Ubuntu tweak and unsettings so I removed them but the default themes and custom ones are still messed up I ran `unity --reset` and this is what I get:

```
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values    
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins    
Initializing core options...done    
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1200004    
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x38000af    
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x32000ad    
Initializing composite options...done    
Initializing opengl options...done    
Initializing decor options...done    
Initializing vpswitch options...done    
Initializing snap options...done    
Initializing mousepoll options...done    
Initializing resize options...done    
Initializing place options...done    
Initializing move options...done    
Initializing wall options...done    
Initializing grid options...done    
Initializing session options...done    
Initializing gnomecompat options...done    
Initializing animation options...done    
Initializing fade options...done    
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done    
Initializing workarounds options...done    
Initializing scale options...done    
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture    
Initializing expo options...done    
Initializing ezoom options...done    
(compiz:4749): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed    
Initializing unityshell options...done    
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc0009e!    
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.    
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!    
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.    
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!    
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.    
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a4!    
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.    
WARN  2012-07-02 19:51:42 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.    
WARN  2012-07-02 19:51:42 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.    
WARN  2012-07-02 19:51:42 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.    
WARN  2012-07-02 19:51:42 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.    
WARN  2012-07-02 19:51:42 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.    
Initializing addhelper options...done    
Initializing animationaddon options...done    
Initializing annotate options...done    
Initializing bench options...done    
Initializing blur options...done    
Initializing clone options...done    
Initializing colorfilter options...done    
Initializing commands options...done    
Initializing crashhandler options...done    
Initializing cube options...done    
Initializing cubeaddon options...done    
Initializing extrawm options...done    
Initializing fadedesktop options...done    
Initializing firepaint options...done    
Initializing group options...done    
Initializing imgjpeg options...done    
Initializing kdecompat options...done    
Initializing loginout options...done    
Initializing mag options...done    
Initializing maximumize options...done    
Initializing mblur options...done    
Initializing neg options...done    
Initializing notification options...done    
Initializing obs options...done    
Initializing opacify options...done    
Initializing put options...done    
Initializing reflex options...done    
Initializing resizeinfo options...done    
Initializing ring options...done    
Initializing rotate options...done    
Initializing scaleaddon options...done    
Initializing scalefilter options...done    
Initializing screenshot options...done    
Initializing shelf options...done    
Initializing shift options...done    
Initializing showdesktop options...done    
Initializing showmouse options...done    
Initializing splash options...done    
Initializing staticswitcher options...done    
Initializing switcher options...done    
Initializing td options...done    
Initializing thumbnail options...done   
Initializing trailfocus options...done    
Initializing wallpaper options...done    
Initializing water options...done    
Initializing widget options...done    
Initializing winrules options...done    
Initializing wobbly options...done    
ERROR 2012-07-02 19:51:43 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
Setting Update "main_menu_key"    
Setting Update "run_key"    
Setting Update "autoraise"    
Setting Update "autoraise_delay"
```

Any Ideas? this is very inconvenient some of the text like in additional drivers are unreadable because they come out White

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The easiest way, but a rather drastic one for me was to boot into a terminal only session and used the following procedure:

1. Boot up Ubuntu till the login-screen.
2. Pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal screen.
3. Loggged in with my credentials at the prompt.
4. Used a program called `htop` to kill any process using graphical resources.
5. `sudo apt-get remove unity`
6. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
7. And finally `sudo apt-get install unity`.
8. `sudo reboot`

My system came alive without any problems, logged in using my credentials and could work normally.

Comment: tried this but did not fix my problem completely but thanks anyway